# Firebase onIdTokenChanged not giving refreshed token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase in a react project where I want to receive refreshed tokens from firebase once the previous one is deleted automatically after 1 hr.

I went through the docs and found

> onIdTokenChanged

So my question is I just had to call "onIdTokenChanged" once after login? Or do I need to call it before every API request and sent it to the backend for verification?

As of now what I'm doing is as soon as user clicks on Login Button I'm calling a function and inside that below is the code:

```
    const signInWithEmailAndPassword = async () => {
        dispatch({ type: SET_IS_LOADING, payload: true })
        try {
          dispatch({ type: 'LOADING' })
          await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    
          return firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(async user => {
            if (user) {
              const token = await user.getIdToken()
              alert('user123 inside firebaseAuth')
              Cookies.set('token', token, { domain: domain }, { sameSite: 'strict' }, { secure: true })
    
              await dispatch({
                type: 'LOGIN',
                payload: {
                  token,
                  user: {
                    email: user.email,
                    name: data.userLogin.firstName,
                    uuid: user.uid
                  }
                }
              })
            } else {
              dispatch({ type: 'LOGOUT' })
            }
          })
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
          dispatch({ type: SET_IS_LOADING, payload: false })
        }
      }
```

What else should I do to keep receiving new refreshed tokens when the previous expires?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you redirect user to any other page after login? If yes then the idTokenChanged observer maybe disconnected...

Comment: yes i redirect to "/" from "/login", so whats the workaround for this ? @Dharmaraj

Comment: You could "lift state up"... in other words, move the `firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged` higher in the ReactTree to a more long lived component, probably something above your app container.

Comment: When you redirect user to a different page, the `onIdTokenChanged()` may disconnect if the page refreshes or the component is changed. There should be an instance of `onIdTokenChanged`.